# real time notification by JSON format in android

Tags: android, api, notifications

i have an application about football/soccer , i'm using API for get information about the matches, i need a way to make a real time notification when a goal is added in this API which have a JSON format .

Comment: Can you post some code? 
Did you try `NotificationCompat`?

Comment: i didn't write any code for this yet , i need a method that can used in this situation

Comment: StackOverflow is to be used if you have any problems in solving a problem. Atleast try first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to your back end web service code, look into Google cloud messaging(gcm) service, it is made precisely for this purpose. If it is not feasible to use gcm, you need to set a repeating alarm, but it will not be as accurate as gcm. But I highly recommend going for gcm. Here's a link for your reference. [GCM dev docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

Another work around for the case where you don't have access to source code for back end is to develop a middle layer sort of web service that keeps polling your back end and uses gcm to alert the clients. This way atleast you won't be wasting user's system resources.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pop a notification:

```
Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_notification)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 200, 200, 200})
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build()); //id is the notification id, if you use the same id, the notification will override the previous
```

Comment: thank you but my question is how to pop up this notification in a particular time when the data in the API request is changed

Comment: do you have a listener? how do you know that the data has changed?

Comment: the data changes according to the events in the match , should i call this request every one minute to know if any changes happened or there is any method can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the functionality,

1. Use a service to frequently(maybe once in 5 minutes) check information about the match.
2. If you have any Updates, show a notification to the user.

To show Notification:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setTicker("Ticker Text").setSmallIcon("Icon").setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Content Text").setContentIntent(pi).setAutoCancel(true).build();
                                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                                notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

For more info use this link
[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is have a `Receiver` that will run and check for updates. For real time updates, I would use a Socket.

It pretty much depends on your server.